# Node webkit multiple folder selection

Tags: node.js, npm, node-webkit

I have this code:

```
<input style="display:none;" id="fileDialog" type="file" nwdirectory multiple/>
```

Unfortunately it only allows selection of a single folder, whereas selecting multiple folders would be very beneficial. Are there any options/solutions to make selecting multiple folders in a Node webkit project feasible?

Comment: I would also like to know if this is possible!